# torch model.load_state_dict *** AttributeError: 'ModelName' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

i previously saved a model like this:

```py
trainedmodelpath = "model.th"
torch.save({'model': model,
            'scaler': scaler,
            'encoder': label_encoder,
            'config': config_parameters},
            trainedmodelpath)
```

But when i try to load it like this:

```py
PreviousModelPath = "model.th"
TorchLoadedState = torch.load(PreviousModelPath)
TorchLoadedState_Model = TorchLoadedState['model']
model.load_state_dict(TorchLoadedState_Model)
```

i received this error

```py
*** AttributeError: 'ModelName' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save model weigths with `model.state_dict()` instead:

```
torch.save({'model': model.state_dict(),
            'scaler': scaler,
            'encoder': label_encoder,
            'config': config_parameters},
            trainedmodelpath)
```